# Как вывести значение переменной в процентах? jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Здравствуйте. Такой вопрос: есть такой вот кусочек кода

```
$("header").css({
    height: res
});
```

В переменную **res** я сохраняю нужное мне значение высоты шапки сайта. Собственно в чем проблема: оно сохраняет значение в **px** , а мне нужно в **%**.
Подскажите, как это возможно сделать?

З.Ы. Если что - простите, я занимаюсь этим относительно не долго и могу не знать элементарного :)

Comment: `height: res + '%'` пробовали?

Comment: спасибо большое, помогло

Answer (score 1):

Ответ из комментариев, который помог решить задачу

```
height: res + '%'
```